# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js) May 2023

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

```html
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
 Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'
```

As of today I'm getting this error in any React project I create. A new version of Babel also happened to release today so I'm assuming it has something to do with that. I'm a beginner with this stuff, I was working through a Udemy course when this error popped up so I'm not the best at problem solving these errors yet.

The solutions I found were all dated back to around 2018-2020, and didn't help in my situation when I attempted them.